# Parse.com fetching same data

Tags: android, android-fragments, parse-platform

I have a code that fetches entries from parse.com. When the user enters the fragment for the first time it works fine but when the user enters the fragment for the second time one entry is displayed for multiple times.

First time:- [image: first time]

Second time:- [image: second time]

Here is my code:-

```
public class ReportHistoryFragment extends Fragment {

    View reportHistory;
    ParseUser parseUser;
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> parseQuery,pq;
    ParseObject parseObject;
    String title,desc;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    ParseFile parseFile;
    Context context;
    Card card;
    ArrayList<Card> cards;
    CardListView cardListView;
    CardArrayAdapter cardArrayAdapter;
    int size,i=0;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    Iterator<ParseObject> iterator;

    public ReportHistoryFragment() {

    **}
    @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    public ReportHistoryFragment(Context context) {
        this.context=context;
    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        reportHistory = inflater.inflate(R.layout.report_history_layout,container,false);
        cardListView = (CardListView) reportHistory.findViewById(R.id.listcard);
        parseUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context,"Downloading Data","Please wait...",true);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        downloadData();
        return reportHistory;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }
    public void downloadData() {
        parseQuery=null;
        pq=null;
        cards = new ArrayList<>();
        parseQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Reports");
        parseQuery.whereEqualTo("user",parseUser);
        parseQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> parseObjects, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    iterator = parseObjects.iterator();
                    size = parseObjects.size();
                    i=0;
                    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                        parseObject = iterator.next();
                        pq = ParseQuery.getQuery("Reports");
                        pq.getInBackground(parseObject.getObjectId(), new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                                if (e == null) {
                                    title = object.getString("title");
                                    desc = object.getString("description");
                                    parseFile = (ParseFile) object.get("image");
                                    parseFile.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void done(byte[] bytes, ParseException e) {
                                            if(e==null) {
                                                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes,0,bytes.length);
                                            } else {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                            card = new HistoryItemCard(getActivity(),title,desc,bitmap);
                                            cards.add(card);
                                            i++;
                                            if(i==size) {
                                                cardArrayAdapter = new CardArrayAdapter(getActivity(),cards);
                                                cardArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                                cardListView.setAdapter(cardArrayAdapter);
                                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } else {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Please someone help me!

Comment: Make sure you are passing correct data whichever you are populating in the recyclerview.

Comment: I am passing the correct data else it wont for the work for the first time also and i am not using recycler view